# How fixed error: pvrsrvallocdevicemem error 1 returned when set background?

Tags: android

My Image (bg.png): 400x800
Set background:

```
 layoutmain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

In logcat display error: `pvrsrvallocdevicemem error 1 returned`
How fixed error: pvrsrvallocdevicemem error 1 returned when set background?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the background image with 9-patch if possible.